# Accessing server variables with IIS url rewriter

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have one site with multiple domains bound to it. Here's what I'm trying to achieve

A user access a resource at `http://theirdomain.com/admin` based on their domain name I would need to rewrite all requests to `http://theirdomain.com/admin/theirdomain.com`. The idea is that the actual user specific resources are living in seperate folders on the server but I want to map them up based on their domain. Not quite sure how to setup a rewrite rule for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got as far as this which might help:

```
<rule name="rww" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^((admin)|(admin/))$" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/admin/{C:2}" />
</rule>
```